# App is stuck/breaks in onResume or onPause

Tags: android, sockets, android-activity, focus, pause

So I made an app which uses sockets, buffered readers etc. to communicate with a server. Everything works, but when I unfocus the app (by pressing that "show me all of the running apps" button) and then refocus it, it is frozen. I tried to close the sockets, readers etc. in onPause, and I tried it without even overriding the onPause method (and onResume).

I basically want the app to return to the main activity as soon as it looses focus, but I can't just finish the current activity (because then the app freezes when you focus it again, too).

What do I have to do? 
I would provide some code, but I don't think that it would be helpful for the question. But if you need some, tell me and I will post it.

Comment: are you doing your long running operation on the background thread?

Comment: I have an AsyncTask which has a `while(running)` loop... setting `running` to false doesn't help

Comment: put the onresume and onpause of your code

Comment: Async tasks all happen on the same thread.  So if you have a while(running) loop, you're probably stopping all other async tasks from executing ever.  Use a Thread instead

Comment: I used to use a Thread but it didn't work either so I thought an AsyncTask might help

Comment: @diegoveloper what do you mean? If you mean "off your code"; I already did that. Removing them did not help

Comment: Put the code in your answer

Comment: @diegoveloper the code of what exactly? My asyncTask?